# Portlet Preference value not getting changed

Tags: jakarta-ee, preferences, portlet, portal, oracle-ucm

I am facing a problem in portlet preference where i am unable to change portlet preference value i.e the preference value is not getting changed.

I have changed the value in portlet and then crossed checked in `portlet.xml`, where it is changed. But when i am trying to get this portlet preference value using its key it always gives me the earlier value.

My portlet.xml looks like this:

```
<portlet-preferences>
    <preference>
        <name>DATA_FILE_DOC_NAME</name>// the name of the preference
        <value>COM-EXAMPLE-EDIT</value>// the corresponding value
        <read-only>false</read-only>// extra attribute
    </preference>
</portlet-preferences>
```

And in Java file i am retrieving this preference like this:

```
....

//Getting the portal prefernce object.
    PortletPreferences portletPreference = portletRequest.getPreferences();

    // get the data file doc name.
    dataFileDocName = portletPreference.getValue(
        "DATA_FILE_DOC_NAME", "Not Found!!");

    System.out.println("Data file doc name is : "+dataFileDocName.toUpperCase());
```

I am getting `dataFileDocName` as **COM-EXAMPLE-EDIT** but if I change the preference to something else, still I get the same preference **COM-EXAMPLE-EDIT** (no matter how many times i clean and publish my project).

Please help me out.

Comment: can you show piece of code with which you change (trying to change) preferences?

Answer (score 1):

3 things:

1. portlet preferences can be changed only in action phase
2. call setValue and then store in order to ensure changes to preference are saved
3. read-only preferences cannot be changed, so make sure you dont mark them as read-only in the deployment descriptor.